# Sum returns value when should return 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a really confusing problem. Here it is:

```
[12] pry(EstimatedTime)> EstimatedTime.where(user_id: User.current.id, plan_on: date).pluck(:hours) => [] 
[13] pry(EstimatedTime)> EstimatedTime.where(user_id: User.current.id, plan_on: date).sum(:hours) => 3.0
```

What kind of magic is this?

This statement resides in model method, that is being called from view. Before that, in controller action, i'm calling another method of the same model, that is performing bulk create of records within transaction.

```
def self.save_all(records)
  transaction do
    records.each do |record|
      record.save!
    end
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    return false 
end
```

The exception is being thrown, method returns false, view is rendered and this happens.

**UPD**
I found a workaround, replacing `.sum` with `.pluck(:hours).sum`, but I still have no idea why my first way of doing this fails.

Comment: What do you get if you do `EstimatedTime.where(user_id: User.current.id, plan_on: date).map{|et| et.hours}`?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I get an empty array.

Comment: What are the SQL statements?

Comment: I wonder if there is a caching issue, which is not being applied to the pluck-based method

Comment: @DavidAldridge You're absolutely right, i've enabled SQL logging in pry, and realized, that `.pluck` is actually looking into database, while `.sum` uses database cache.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, *always* look at the queries, that's the lesson here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [David Aldrige](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6742/david-aldridge) pointed out in comments to the question, the problem was that `.sum(:hours)` was using cached data, while `.pluck(:hours)` was actually looking into database.

Why database and query cache contained different data? Well, seems like in Rails 3 (I should probably have specified my rails version when asking question) failed transaction would rollback the database, but leave query cache intact. This led to temporary data inconsistency between database and cache. This was corrected in Rails 4 as pointed out in [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17449) issue.

**Solution 1** aka the one I chose for myself

Clear the query cache after transaction fails. So, the method performing the mass insert within transaction now looks like this:

```
def self.save_all(records)
  transaction do
    records.each do |record|
      record.save!
    end
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
     self.connection.clear_query_cache
     return false 
end
```

**Solution 2**

I personally find this much less elegant, though I cannot compare these solutions performance-wise, so I'll post them both. One can simply write the sum statement like this:

`EstimatedTime.where(user_id: User.current.id, plan_on: date).pluck(:hours).sum`

It will use the database data to calculate sum, bypassing the inconsistent cache problem.